# I am using Hbase 1.0.0 and Apache phoenix 4.3.0 on CDH5.4. When I restart Hbase regionserver is down

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I even tried CDH parcel for Apache Phoenix . 
But same problem exists.

I added phoenix-4.3.0-server.jar in /usr/lib/hbase/lib/ and tried to restart Hbase cluster. But my region server is not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-731?focusedCommentId=27594&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

I Used the above link to solve the issue. Phoenix 4.3.0 server jar requires a method that the hbase cdh 1.0.0 jar does not have.

The above link provides patch provided by cloudera. Just download the code build the phoenix project and add the new phoenix-server jar to hbase/lib directory.